# TFS 2015 build server ignoring agent working dir

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I recently setup a new build server for TFS 2015. ON the build agent properties the working dir was originally set to $(SystemDrive)\$(buildnum)\etc
I changed it to be hard coded to E:\ for all the build agents.

But it still attempts to check out the code under C:\

I have looked in the build definition, the build template and the config.xml and see no reference to c:\ or $(SystemDrive) anywhere.

Why is it ignoring the working directory and how can I get it to build under E:\

EDIT ------

Ok now that I have looked at it a little more what I think is happening is that it is copying the source to C: first and then moving it to E: to actually run the build. Based on $(SourceDir) and the BuildAgent Working directory. That being said I do not know how to configure the $(SourceDir) value to point it to E:\

We dont have enough space on the C: to be able to pull down multiple project folders before copying them to E:

Comment: Did you restart the build agents **and** controller after the change?

Comment: Yes, then I restarted the entire server. Still builds in C:\

Comment: If you use TFS Sidekicks, does it still show the workspace mapped to the old path?

Comment: I had never heard of that app until you mentioned it. I installed it to try but it crashes when I try and run it. OS is windows server 2012. I started looking through the work spaces in visual studio and everyone that I checked was pointed to E:\ but they were all for the old tfs server and probably need to be removed. There are literally hundreds of them.

Comment: Did you install the correct version?  You need Version 6, and it also does not need to be installed on the server (I run it locally on my machine)  It's an amazing tool, I use it all the time to look at workspaces and it's also really good for undoing checkouts.

Comment: Yes I did install version 6. doesnt seem to be working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: By "old tfs server", do you mean literally the old TFS server, or the old build server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106394/discussion-between-overlordchin-and-taegost).

Comment: It's worth noting that if you're setting up TFS build for the first time, you should not be using the XAML build system. It's considered legacy, more or less. Use the newer web-based build system instead.

Comment: Daniel, Thank you for your input. Unfortunately this "new" server is meant to be a replacement for an existing one and support a ton of existing build definitions that all utilize the xaml build system. But I will try my best to avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I figured it out. The build logs said they were getting the workspace. When I compared the time it was taking to previous successful builds I noticed that there was a large discrepancy in the time taken. At this point I started looking for files that should have been pulled down and couldnt find any. So I started looking for where all the space was going.  What was actually happening is the database was rejecting the connections and filling the drive with sql dumps.

Thanks for all the suggestions guys.

EDIT - After running the service pack and cumulative updates for SQL Server the errors went away. TFS now builds on the appropriate drive and the main system drive no longer fills with SQL dump files.

Answer (score 0):

Just changed my build agent Working Directory from `$(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)` to `E:\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)`, then queued a build, the build agent get sources from TFS to my E: driver. No issue occurred.

You can try to clean the cache file on your TFS AT machine: `C:\TfsData\ApplicationTier\_fileCache`

Comment: So this was located at a different path on my machine. I got rid of it and restarted the build service. I then kicked off 2 jobs. Both looked like they were cloning the source to C:\ instead of E:\ as I can see the free space on C:\ rapidly vanishing while the E:\ still has a ton of free space and it doesnt seem to change.

Comment: Value for the $(SourceDir) is what you configure to Working directory settings on the build agent properties. In my example, the $(SourceDir) is "E:\Builds\6\TeamProject\BuildDefinition". If you delete your original working dir on your C driver, you'll only see there is no Builds folder created on C driver any more. Also, check Diagnostics log, under "Get sources from Team Foundation Version Control", you'll see the source gets to E driver, not C driver.